# Connecting router as a switch

Tags: lan, switch, switching

In a home LAN, I have connected one router A (which is also connected to the Internet) to router B but router B is supposed to work only as a switch (I am not using the WAN port in router B at all). Right now there are 2 computers connected directly through Ethernet to router A (and 2 other using WiFi) and 1 computer connected to router (switch) B.

After that I have noticed that on the other machines the Internet stops working for a short periods of time.

What can cause these problems? Should I setup static IP addresses for all of the computers in the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you left the router's DHCP server enabled. Assigning static IP addresses will hide the problem, but you should disable its DHCP server. Also, make sure the router's own IP address is not the same as the other router's IP address.

Comment: Assuming its because DHCP server is enabled, why does it exactly cause connectivity problems (i.e. What happens internally)?

Comment: @REACHUS Most likely, machines get IP addresses issued by that router which make it their default gateway, but it has no route to the Internet (becauss no static route was configured). In addition, both routers might give out the same IP address to different machines. Lots of things can and will go wrong.